# root.mainloop() and bot.run(TOKEN) not working together

Tags: python, tkinter, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot i can control using tkinter. The problem is that if i want to run both the bot and the tkintere program it dosen't work:

```py
bot.run(TOKEN)
root.mainloop()
```

or:

```py
root.mainloop()
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

This happens because both bot.run(TOKEN) and root.mainloop() blocks the next line of code meaning it can't run.

Question: Is there any way i can make both codes run?

Comment: If both of them truly spend most of their time blocked, you can run `bot.run` in a separate thread.  Tkinter has to run in the main thread.

Comment: Both of them block the entire thread, so you'll have to multithread them.